# Does $g_2/(g_1 + 2g_2)^2 = h_2/(h_1 + 2h_2)^2$ have solutions over $\mathbb{N}$ with $g_2 \neq h_2$?

Tags: graph-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the equation
$$\frac{g_2}{(g_1 + 2g_2)^2} = \frac{h_2}{(h_1 + 2h_2)^2}$$
Does this equation have any solutions **over $\mathbb{N}$** which satisfy $g_2 \neq h_2$? I tried using MATLAB and got no such solutions, but apart from not being sure that I did it correctly, I would prefer a proof just to be sure.

For those interested: I got this equation from an interesting problem in graph theory, which asks if a graph $G$ is determined (up to isomorphism) by the sequence $\varphi(G)$ (which is indexed by the set of all connected graphs) with
$$\varphi(G)_F = \frac{\operatorname{Sub}(F, G)}{|G|^{|F|}}$$
where $\operatorname{Sub}(F,G)$ denotes the number of subgraphs of $G$ isomorphic to $F$. If I am correct, the conjecture holds for connected graphs and in general for all graphs whose largest connected component is of size at least $3$, however it is not true for nonempty graphs with no edges (any two such graphs have the same image under $\varphi$). The equation now arises when studying the remaining case, i.e. graphs which are disjoint unions of arbitrarily many copies of $K_1$ and $K_2$. If we set $G = g_1 K_1 + g_2 K_2$ and $H = h_1 K_1 + h_2 K_2$, then $G \cong H$ holds precisely when $(g_1, g_2) = (h_1, h_2)$. Thus, the conjecture does not hold for such graphs iff the equation in question has such solutions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, and great first question! I'm glad you included appropriate context for your diophantine equation (it's actually very interesting).

Comment: By the way, where does your $\varphi(G)_F$ come from? With a slight change to either the numerator or the denominator it could have a nice combinatorial meaning as the probability of getting $F$ when making some appropriate kind of random selection of parts of $G$, but this particular fraction does not have an obvious nice interpretation I can see.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed, I noticed that as well. Originally, the function $\varphi$ is taken from an exercise problem in one of my classes; however the problem asked us to prove that $\varphi$ is injective, so the question was ill-posed. Nevertheless, I set out to investigate for which classes of graphs we can guarantee injectivity, which led me to the findings outlined in the OP. When discussing the issue with the staff, they mentioned something like the denominator representing a probability, but we did not talk about that, so I would presume that they made a mistake when designing $\varphi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Diophantine equation.

$$\frac{x}{(y+2x)^2}=\frac{z}{(q+2z)^2}$$

You can record these decisions.

$$x=ks^2$$

$$y=ns$$

$$q=p(n+2(s-p)k)$$

$$z=kp^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution, indeed that confirms my suspicions of messing up the symbolic computation.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the below equation is:

$\frac{x}{(y+2x)^2}=\frac{z}{(q+2z)^2}$

$(x)=(n+2)^2$

$(z)= (m+2)^2$

$y=m(n+2)^2$

$q=n(m+2)^2$

For $(m,n)=(7,3)$ we have:

$(x,z,y,q)=(25, 81, 175,243)$

Answer (score 0):

You can just pick a large $R$ and set
$$ g_1 = 1 \qquad g_2 = R-2g_1 $$
$$ h_1 = 4 \qquad h_2 = 2R-2h_1 $$
$$ k_1 = 9 \qquad k_2 = 3R-2k_1 $$
and so forth.

If you pick $R$ large enough you can get arbitrarily many expressions for $\frac{1}{R^2}$ in the shape $\frac{x}{(y+2x)^2}$.